# Web page different resolutions fitting

Tags: html, css

I am first year student Software Engineering and I use to have an assignment to make a web page. It is not complicated at all but after writing the web page I realised that when you open the site  in smaller resolution (than mine 1080p) device it doesn't fit very well. I don't know what resolution uses the teacher who is going to assess me so i want to modify the site for 1600;900 and 1336:768 at least.
I should say that I used other suggestions that I should divide div tags by % not by pixels but it still doesnt work.
I googled the problem and I think I found a solution - actualy it is something with @media where you can set different percentages for different screen resolutions in advance and then you get the cliend screen resolution and open it in appropriate proportions

So I wanted to ask you how exactly to write this?
P.s you could take a look at my webpage [here](http://users.aber.ac.uk/dpv/cs15020/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on how intricate your site is, what the layout looks like, and what elements need to do at what sizes.

In general, HTML is "fluid" by default, so text will wrap, and elements will resize to fit their contents, so if your design is simplistic, you shouldn't have to do anything.

When you start sizing things with absolute/static pixel sizes, you get yourself into situations where things no longer fit.

You should generally avoid making designs that are fixed pixel sizes, and allow for elements to re-size naturally as HTML is designed to do.

---

`@media` queries are appropriate for changing appearances at specific resolutions, and are generally set up to make "responsive" designs, where elements can change styling or be hidden/shown at different resolutions. This is usually used for more complicated or dynamic layouts, and still needs to be planned for accordingly, because it is usually set up to accommodate a range of resolutions. For example an element might be 100% wide from 0 to 1024 pixels wide, and become 50% wide when the window is over 1024 pixels wide.

---

In the case of your web site, you are sort of breaking it by floating everything left. `float` tends to be really over-used in CSS without understanding its side effects.

Remove `width` from your `menu` element, and remove `width` and `float` from your `content` element.

This will cause the menu to be as wide as its contents (the buttons) and "float" next to the contents, which will try to be 100% wide, but be narrowed to allow the menu to fit next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck in school you will need to read up on `responsive` design which you acheave via CSS.
eg.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  // Write your style
}
@media screen and (min-width: 501px){
  // Write your style
}
```

That is what you need to do, there is lot of documentation and tutorials on this you will have no problem finding the resources.

Here is a TutsPlus page to get you started: [Tutorial link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/new-course-responsive-web-design-revisited--cms-22995)